# using sed for search and replace multi-digits

Tags: sed

i have the following list of files:

```
r1 r2 10 r11 r99
```

I am trying to replace all the numbers after the *r* in the file names  in an ls output

result i am looking for:

```
 rA rA  rA  rA  rA
```

Using the following sed command i can match files r1 r2 but not r10 r11 and r99

```
   ls | sed -e 's/r[0-9]/rA/'
```

It provides me with the following output:

```
rA
rA0
rA1
rA
rA9
```

Appreciate if someone can point out what i am missing in the sed search pattern, can sed be used to match multiple digit numbers at all?

thank you.

Answer (score 6):

`[0-9]` will match one digit.

`[0-9]*` will match zero or more digits.

You likely want `[0-9]\+` which will match one or more digits.

You can also use `[0-9]\{1,\}` to match one or more digits.

Comment: thank, this worked for me
 `sed -e 's/r[0-9]\{1,\}/rA/'`

Comment: mark the answer if it satisfy your question

Comment: @sergey Thank you. I was going crazy. For me it didn't work with `\+`